# Using Python3 how can I split a df with a column of one set of ranges into a df with multiple subranges?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have the following:

```
#this is the data we have
df = pd.DataFrame(data=(['A','1-50', 10],['B','25-200', 15],['C','25-300', 5]), columns=['Category','Range', 'Qty'])

#these are the different range categories we need to have.
list_of_ranges = ['1-10', '10-25', '25-50', '50-100', '100-200', '200-300', '300-400']

# insert magic spells here

#this is what the result needs to look like
results = pd.DataFrame(data=(['A','1-25', 10],['A','25-50', 10],['B','25-50', 15],['B','50-100', 15],['B','100-200', 15],['C','25-50', 15],['C','50-100', 15],['C','100-200', 15],['C','200-300', 5]), columns=['Category','Range', 'Qty'])
```

As per the example above:

I have a df with ranges that need to be broken to subranges all columns need to be duplicated except for the new range.
How can I do that?

Edit1:
Example of the logic

Area "A" has temperatures ranging from 1-50 degrees Celsius for 10 days per year.
This is a single row that reads:

```
1: A,1-50,10
```

This same row can be interpreted as: in Area "A" temperature ranges can be 1-10, 10-25, or 25-50 for 10 days per year.
So I would like to have 3 rows:

```
1: A,1-10,10
2: A,10-25,10
3: A,25-50,10
```

Comment: What is the logic behind breaking into subranges?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with the [Pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) practicing the examples.

Comment: @MayankPorwal please see Edit1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a couple of functions to work with 'ranges' as you defined them, but otherwise it is a matter of creating a list of 'small ranges' for each 'Range' in the df that are 'inside' it, and then `explode`-ing the df

```
def split_range(r):
    """
    split range into a tuple. range is a string 'xx-yy'
    """
    tokens =  r.split('-')
    return (int(tokens[0]), int(tokens[1]))

def is_inside(r1,r2):
    """
    True if range r1 is inside r2. Range is a string 'xx-yy'
    """
    t1, t2 = split_range(r1), split_range(r2)
    return (t1[0]>=t2[0]) and (t1[1] <= t2[1])

df['small_ranges'] = df.apply(lambda row: [rng for rng in list_of_ranges if is_inside(rng, row['Range']) ], axis=1)
```

this produces

```
    Category    Range      Qty  small_ranges
--  ----------  -------  -----  -----------------------------------------
 0  A           1-50        10  ['1-10', '10-25', '25-50']
 1  B           25-200      15  ['25-50', '50-100', '100-200']
 2  C           25-300       5  ['25-50', '50-100', '100-200', '200-300']
```

now we `explode`

```
df.explode('small_ranges')
```

output

```
    Category    Range      Qty  small_ranges
--  ----------  -------  -----  --------------
 0  A           1-50        10  1-10
 0  A           1-50        10  10-25
 0  A           1-50        10  25-50
 1  B           25-200      15  25-50
 1  B           25-200      15  50-100
 1  B           25-200      15  100-200
 2  C           25-300       5  25-50
 2  C           25-300       5  50-100
 2  C           25-300       5  100-200
 2  C           25-300       5  200-300
```

Comment: Had a question regarding your answer but figured it out.
The answer is absolutely beautiful.
Thank you!

Comment: @Michael, thank you! It was a nice question to figure out

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a solution using `pandas.Interval`, which seems pretty useful for this case. First we convert your strings to `pd.Interval`

```
list_of_ranges = [pd.Interval(*tuple(map(int, r.split('-')))) for r in list_of_ranges]

df['Range'] = df['Range'].apply(lambda r: pd.Interval(*tuple(map(int, r.split('-')))))
```

The we create a new DataFrame including all desired ranges for each original range:

```
my_temps = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    _df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    _df['Range'] = [r for r in list_of_ranges if r.overlaps(row['Range'])]
    _df['Category'], _df['Qty'] = row['Category'], row['Qty']

    my_temps.append(_df)

final_df = pd.concat(my_temps).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then we finally convert the ranges again to their original string format:

```
final_df['Range'] = final_df['Range'].apply(lambda r: '{}-{}'.format(r.left, r.right))
```

Which results in the following dataframe:

```
  Category    Range  Qty
0        A     1-10   10
1        A    10-25   10
2        A    25-50   10
0        B    25-50   15
1        B   50-100   15
2        B  100-200   15
0        C    25-50    5
1        C   50-100    5
2        C  100-200    5
3        C  200-300    5
```

Let us know if you have any further issues!

Comment: This seems like a good answer as well. Thank you! The other answer seemed a but neater to me thought.